# Strange effect in preview mode if a heading markdown is immediately followed by a code markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Please press the edit button to bring you in preview/edit mode. See what happens in the preview area. The code markdown does not work well in case A, i.e., the first code line is not displayed as code but as normal text.

In case B, I insert any object between the heading and code markdowns, now everything works as expected.

I am using Google Chrome and Firefox on Windows, I confirm it might be a bug.

### Case A: Heading markdown is immediately followed by a code markdown

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
.%my code goes here
\end{document}
```

### Case B: Heading markdown is not immediately followed by a code markdown

=== any object can be here to make the code markdown work ===

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
.%my code goes here
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works for me (Firefox 4, Ubuntu) in the final post. In the edit window the first code line is not displayed as code but as normal text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same issue as reported [in this questions on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95426/incorrect-markdown-preview-of-list-items-after-a-header) (and totally my fault); it's fixed in the code already and will work correctly again after the next build of the sites (we deploy at least once a day, usually more often).

Comment: +1 Thank you balpha.